# REST - Partial Resources

Tags: json, rest

It's common in a REST design to allow partial resources to be returned. In this case; I want to allow the user specify only certain fields of a resource to be returned in the JSON representation of that resource.

For example lets say we have a resource Person:

```
{
   "id": 12,
   "name":{
          "first":"Angie",
          "last": "Smith",
          "middle": "joy",
          "maiden": "crowly",
    },
    "address": {
          "street": "1122 Something St.",
          ..and so on...
    },
... and so on
}
```

Lets say that list of params is pretty long.  And lets say I have an API consumer who at the beginning of creating the API design wants only a couple fields like id and name.first back.  I'm assuming it's common to allow something like this:

/person?fields=id,name

where fields says I only want those fields back.

The question I have is, should then the Person resource return all fields with nulls and just those fields with values OR should it just return the Person representation with only fields id and name and you literally remove all the other params dynamically from the backend.

Seems like #2 is cleaner, but does it make sense to do that in REST, or do people normally return all other fields (to make sure we're keeping the representation in terms of structure/schema consistent/reliable) with nulls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you suggested, option 2 is cleaner and YES it makes sense to do that in REST.

Adding null defeats part of the purpose of partial responses as it makes the response body larger than it needs to be.

An example of the use case you described is shown on the Google Developer Forum; in the [Partial Response](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/performance) section.

Comment: excellent link, the kind of link I've been looking for!  I'm battling trying to get our web team to understand we're building a REST API, not a "hey platform team, you need to create the API contract based on MY application's component structures".  NO we provide you what you need, but we have certain conventions we expect you to adhere by for our API to get that info.  WTF!  Ok so web team, you are saying you are designing our API?  This is the crap I'm dealing with right now.  I told they you will eventually be able to specify subsets of fields (partials) but we are just starting this API

Comment: sometimes I wish I just owned a fing coffee shop and don't have to deal with ignorance from web teams.  This shi* is just way too stressful, we can't even constructively come to a consensus where I work on designing sh** well.

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about is a different representation of the same resource. Both representations are valid, but in my opinion #2 makes more sense, because the response is smaller, and if you don't want to display the values you usually don't need the property names either.

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend a bit the two great previous responses about partial responses, you could also consider the header `Prefer` instead of using the query parameter `fields`.

See the following links for more details:

- The specification: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240
- Irakli Nadareishvili wrote an awesome blog post on this subject: http://www.freshblurbs.com/blog/2015/06/25/api-representations-prefer.html

Hope it helps you,
Thierry