# REST API - Naming convention - Return collection of objects, but only a single property of these items

Tags: rest, naming-conventions

I have a db with a collection of Member objects.

I have a method (GET) that returns all theses Member objects, but only a single property (in this case, "Id") - so not really Member objects, but rather an array of strings.

Which of the following routes/requests would best describe what I am returning (if any)?

```
GET .../api/members/ids
GET .../api/members
GET .../api/memberIds
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855356/rest-partial-resources) we can have it like 
`GET .../api/members?fields=id`

Comment: Saw that thread after asking, I guess I'll let the powers that be decide if they want to keep this open. Thank you very much for you answer.